# java LinkedList's LinkedList.isEmpty() method not working properly?

Tags: java, linked-list

Actually, I'm using one thread to insert elements in one LinkedList and another thread to remove these elements from the LinkedList(). Before removing I want to check is LinkedList contains element or not so I'm using **LinkedList.isEmpty()** method but it is not working as I'm expecting. **I want to know reason behind that!**

**Here is my sample code:**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Demo {

    private LinkedList li;

    private Demo() {
        li = new LinkedList();
    }

    public void insert() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            li.add(i);
            System.out.println("inserted : " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void remove() {
        while (true) {
            if (li.isEmpty()) {
                //System.out.println("this statement has no significance..."); // Line Number 27
            } else {
                int a = (int) li.poll();
                System.out.println("removed : " + a);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Demo main = new Demo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                main.insert();
            }
        };
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                main.remove();
            }
        };
        t2.start();
        while (true) {

        }
    }

}
```

**My Observations:**

- If I uncomment Line Number 27 from above code it is properly working. **Why?**
- If I don't want this SOP Statement on Line Number 27. I just want to check LinkedList is empty or not and if not empty then I want to poll from it. **How I can achieve this situation?**

Comment: You're reading and writing a non-thread-safe data structure from multiple threads. That can't possibly be reliable. You need to learn about thread-safety, atomicity, synchronzation, etc.

Comment: @JBNizet- Okay I understand the situation but How I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Search for Java thread synchronization, there's lots of documentation and techniches, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm

Comment: By properly synchronizing all the accesses to the list, and making sure your check-then-act operations (like checking if the list is not empty, then polling) is part of the same, atomic, synchronized block. That's a big, complex subject. You can't just learn about that in 2 minutes. Read "Java Concurrency in Practice", by Brian Goetz. Or at the very least the Java tutorial about threads.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of functionality you should use a thread-safe structure such as a `BlockingQueue`. Specifically you could use the [poll(long,TimeUnit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method.

The reason adding the `sop` fixes the issue is that it adds a small delay each time around the loop. If there is no delay you are effectively spinning in a tight loop without giving the JVM any opportunity to switch threads.